# Java, Jackson, convert object to xml, problem with invalid characters

Tags: java, xml, serialization, jackson

I'm trying to convert an object to xml using jackson

```
XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
            xmlMapper.configure(ToXmlGenerator.Feature.WRITE_XML_DECLARATION, true);
            xmlMapper.writeValue(createFileResult.getFile(), detailsProductDTOs);
```

however, because my object somewhere contains invalid character for xml, I get an error. Is there some way to tell jackson to ignore this kind of characters? or any other solution?

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Invalid white space character (0xb) in text to output (in xml 1.1, could output as a character entity)
    at com.ctc.wstx.api.InvalidCharHandler$FailingHandler.convertInvalidChar(InvalidCharHandler.java:56)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.XmlWriter.handleInvalidChar(XmlWriter.java:629)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BufferingXmlWriter.writeCharacters(BufferingXmlWriter.java:583)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.writeCharacters(BaseStreamWriter.java:469)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.ser.ToXmlGenerator.writeString(ToXmlGenerator.java:588)
```

Comment: please share the code related with object and it's data

Comment: Could you just remove the invalid characters from the strings in your DTOs using [removing invalid XML characters from a string in java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4237625) or [Stripping Invalid XML characters in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/93655) or [Filtering illegal XML characters in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2897085)?

Comment: dbc , I can't solve my problem in this way because its very complex object, it will be very ugly and buggy code if I'll try to check every string that it contains

Answer (score 3):

Finally, I solved the problem by myself.
As error indicates xml 1.1 supports this kind of characters.
So its possible to solve the problem just by adding following configuration:

```
xmlMapper.configure(ToXmlGenerator.Feature.WRITE_XML_1_1, true);
```